# How to create function in Vertca?

Tags: sql, vertica

I began to study vertiсa. I tryis created customer function but getting error. Help me pliase
My code sql

```
create or REPLACE FUNCTION itog_report_status.get_warn_lvl(day_count NUMERIC)
returns varchar
AS $function$
DECLARE res varchar ;
BEGIN 
select status::varchar
from itog_reports_status.status_warn_level
where days = (
select MIN(days)
from itog_reports_status.status_warn_level
where day_count <= days);
RETURN COALESCE(res, 'RED')
END;
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Syntax error at or near "select"

Comment: Hi Alexander - you might want to check the Vertica docu on this topic
[https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/CREATEFUNCTIONSQLFunctions.htm](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/CREATEFUNCTIONSQLFunctions.htm)

There it says:
The `CREATE FUNCTION` definition allows only one `RETURN` expression. `FROM`, `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY`, `LIMIT`, aggregation, analytics, and meta function are not allowed. `SELECT` , too, by the way ..